# Gerrit Replication.config

Tags: gerrit

I have a remote server ABC with 3 repositories code jellybean, Kitkat and lollipop.
Now I want to do replication only Lollipop repository on Another server XYZ.
Can anyone help me with the replication.config.
How do i write replication.config.

```
Gerrit document says 
[remote "host-one"]
url = gerrit2@host-one.example.com:/some/path/${name}.git

[remote "pubmirror"]
url = mirror1.us.some.org:/pub/git/${name}.git
 url = mirror2.us.some.org:/pub/git/${name}.git
  url = mirror3.us.some.org:/pub/git/${name}.git
  push = +refs/heads/*
  push = +refs/tags/*
  threads = 3
```

Should i mention both host ABC and mirror XYZ URL??
Please explain with example

Comment: Your config looks good. Especially the host-one.  I didn't check the documentation multiple URLs are allowed.  What is the error you are getting in the log file? You did not mention what kind of systems you want to replicate to (gerrit, gitlab, or other kinds). Do both hosts have the ssh key (gerrit the private and the mirrors the public one) and required authentication?

Comment: @volker : I am working on replication of gerrit. Now that my replication works well. I have doubt on .repo folder of replicated repository. There is no manifest.xml and other files inside .repo. Only git projects are being replicated. why not other files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable replication.
First we need to make the mirror of existing repository on slave server.
Then in replication.config in master use projects: to mention repository name.